# SQLLDR / BCP equivalent for DB2

Tags: db2

My product needs to support Oracle, SQLServer, and DB2 v9.  We are trying to figure out the most efficient way to periodically load data into the database.  This currently takes 40+ minutes with individual insert statements, but just a few minutes when we use SQLLDR or BCP.  Is there an equivalent in DB2 that allows CSV data to be loaded into the database quickly?

Our software runs on windows, so we need to assume that the database is running on a remote system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

load:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/r0008305.htm

Answer (score 1):

If  the data is in CSV format try import the data with the delimiter as coma(,)

```
db2 import from <filename> of del modified by coldel, insert into <Table Nmae>
```

Or else you ca use Load command - load from file

```
db2 load client from /u/user/data.del of del
  modified by coldel, insert into mytable
```